# Passing variables to object key function and back to requesting function

Tags: javascript, object

Seems like I can only create a global variable for this to work but here is what would be ideal. I would like to pass a variable to an object which has keys that reference functions. In the function I am referencing I would like to set either that variable or one that was defined within the function that called it and pass it back:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tYLbp/)

```
var methodHandler = {
    'a-key': function () {
        aVariable = document.getElementById('a-container');
    }
}

function sample() {
    var aVariable;

    methodHandler['a-key']();
    console.log(aVariable);
}

sample();
```

Comment: This looks like nonsense to me, what do you exactly want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `this` element. The `this` element, when referenced inside a function of the object, represents the object itself, so doing `this.foo = 1` will actually create a property called `foo` with the value of `1` in your object.

Here is the correct form of the code:

```
var methodHandler = {
    'a-key': function () {
        this.aVariable = document.getElementById('a-container');
        return this.aVariable;
    }
}

function sample() {
    // You can do this:
    methodHandler['a-key']();
    console.log(methodHandler['aVariable']);

    // Or you can do this instead:
    console.log(methodHandler['a-key']());
}

sample();
```

When you call `methodHandler['a-key']()`, the property `aVariable` will be set in your object, so if you log the object you'll see this:

```
console.log(methodHandler);
// Object {a-key: function, aVariable: div#a-container}
```

Comment: If `this` is not set in a function e.g. by instantiating it with `new` or by setting it with `bind` or `apply`, `this` will reference the global scope. Using it here does not gain you anything.

Comment: So this gives you the right to vote down my answer? Obviously if you call it with `apply` the `this` element will change (it is the reason the `apply` function was created...). But this is not the case, and my solution works. You are instead assigning the value to an empty object... and I don't see where the OP told this.

Comment: It is bad practice to use a function's `this` variable without first binding it via `new` or `bind` or `apply`. That is why it was downvoted; not because the `this` might change, but because you're changing global state possibly inadvertently. It is not obvious here that if OP creates a variable named `aVariable` in the global scope that calling `sample()` will clobber his value.

Comment: You're wrong in this case @cvializ. `methodHandler` is an object, and when you call `methodHandler['a-key']()` the `this` keyword will be set to `methodHandler`. It won't do anything in the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

Because of scoping, you can't really do it that way. However, you could restructure it like this and get a similar result:

```
var methodHandler = {
    'a-key': function () {
        return document.getElementById('a-container');
    }
}

function sample() {
    var aVariable = methodHandler['a-key']();
    console.log(aVariable);
}

sample();
```